# Views filter criteria groups OR not working?

Tags: views

I have a view with `FILTER CRITERIA` set. I have three groups, each joined by `AND`s, with the criteria within each group `OR`ed. The final group are two taxonomy terms, meaning I want my query to return nodes that have one term or 
the other. No node will have both of the tags set.

[image]
[image]

However, when I see the SQL in the preview, the terms seem are connected by a `AND`. 
[image]

```
WHERE (((node__field_event_categories.field_event_categories_target_id = '434')) AND ((node__field_event_categories2.field_event_categories_target_id = '212'))) AND ((taxonomy_index.status = '1') AND (((DATE_FORMAT((node__field_date_range.field_date_range_value + INTERVAL -14400 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s') >= DATE_FORMAT(('2018-10-22T04:00:00' + INTERVAL -14400 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s'))) OR ((DATE_FORMAT((node__field_date_range.field_date_range_end_value + INTERVAL -14400 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s') >= DATE_FORMAT(('2018-10-22T04:00:00' + INTERVAL -14400 SECOND), '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i:%s')))))
```

This causes my query not to return any results.

I've tried removing each tid, one by one, and when one is missing I get results. So I'm thinking I should get both sets of results when they are set to `OR`.

To make sure I was reading the SQL correctly, I ran it through a pretty-printer:

[image]

To double check, I exported the views config, to see what the yaml said about the WHERE clause, and it all seems to be `OR` within the groups:

[image]

I even re-imported the configuration from this yaml, but I still get the same results.

How can I get my taxonomy criteria to function using `OR`?

**Edit**
In the course of troubleshooting, I tried to simplify the filter criteria. I removed everything, all groups and criteria. This is what I have now:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is Drupal 8.6.2. We just updated, so I'm wondering if this is a new bug.

Comment: This might be an instance of this bug: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2559961

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2906185#comment-12401517) on a related (perhaps duplicate?) issue provided settings that got the display working for me.

First, on each filter criteria, check "Reduce Duplicates".

**EDIT** Actually, the answer I linked says to uncheck the "DISTINCT" in the Advanced settings for the query. However, when I did that, I got duplicates. I unchecked it, and I got the right number of results. So that second step may not be necessary for you.